# В чем можно хранить состояние activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

У меня есть на первом `Activity` список товаров, которые пользователь может отсортировать и отфильтровать. Если же пользователь переходит на второе `Activity`, а потом с помощью `Intent` переходит обратно к первому, то `Activity` просто пересобирается и все действия, которые пользователь проводил над списком (сортировка и фильтрация) не сохраняются. Я читал про `onSaveInstanceState()`, но написано, что он не вызывается, когда экземпляр активности разрушается пользовательским действием (при нажатии клавиши BACK). Как мне в данной ситуации поступить?

Comment: Где ваши данные хранятся между запусками приложения?

Comment: Пока что данные хранятся в локальной базе данных, но в будущем база данных будет храниться на сервере.

Comment: Думаю, что параметры сортировки и фильтрации наиболее разумно будет хранить либо в `SharedPreferences`, как в последнем пункте ответа ниже, либо в самой БД сделать таблицу для этих параметров, если они должны быть связаны с этой БД (на разных устройствах одинаковые параметры при открытии этой БД)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдёт вариант не закрывать первую активность, а просто открывать поверх неё новую. При закрытии второй активности на экране просто появится предыдущая в том состоянии, в каком вы её покинули.

Чтобы это осуществить, не нужно вызывать функцию finish(); при переходите во вторую активность, а вторую активность просто закрывать функцией finish(); без использования Intent. На всякий случай, в AndroidManifest.xml можно указать параметром активности, что ей не нужно закрываться:

```
<activity
....
android:noHistory="false"
</activity>
```

Хотя это не обязательно, т.к. этот атрибут по умолчанию равен false.

Ещё есть вариант держать какой-нибудь public static массив с настройками. Может быть даже записывать настройки в SharedPreferences, чтобы они сохранялись после перезапуска. Изначально задаются какие-нибудь дефолтные настройки. Активность в onCreate каждый раз берёт эти настройки и в соответствии с ними создаёт список.

Comment: Первый очень плохой совет. Активити не на переднем плане может быть уничтожена в любой момент и никто не гарантирует ее сохранность, кроме того, при возврате активити создается заново, а это значит, что прошлое состояние с 99% вероятностью будет потеряно. Статик с настройками тоже легко может стать причиной утечек памяти и тут надо хорошо понимать, что делаешь

Comment: Первый способ я использовал, когда в приложении было мало активностей, но потом их количество увеличилось и такой способ стал не удобен. Получается мне нужно использовать `SharedPreferences`?